# Массовое создание мультисайтов на Worpdress

Tags: wordpress

Есть ли возможность создать массово мультисайты Worpress? Нужно на каждый регион сделать свой поддомен, но вручную долго.

Comment: Напишите командный файл с использованием wp-cli: https://wp-cli.org/

Comment: @KAGGDesign спасибо!